# How can I use git to synchronize with a server that cannot connect to github?

Tags: git, github, networking

There is a server in our laboratory. He can go online, but he cannot visit github, gitlab and other similar websites (the network has some settings). My personal computer can access Github. I need to use an emulator, which can only be run on the server (because it is too big, and it can only run on linux, not on windows). When I use ssh to connect to the server, is there a way to make it access github from my computer's network?

Answer (score 0):

> When I use ssh to connect to the server, is there a way to make it access github from my computer's network?

You *could* set up a forwarding tunnel.  This probably violates whatever rules the laboratory has established.  Otherwise they'd let the computer there reach the ones at GitHub.  So either don't do that, or verify that this is allowed before you do it.

You *could* use `git bundle` to copy files around manually.

You *could* create a mirror clone on your own computer, and use the connection between the laboratory computer and your computer to transfer data from the mirror clone to their machine.

These last two options *might also* violate the security rules.  Again, **the real solution is to find out why that computer is semi-isolated**, not just to work around the existing restrictions.